# Kubernetes: How do I delete PV in the correct manner

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

The stateful set es-data was failing on our test environment and I was asked to delete corresponding PV.

So I deleted the following for es-data:
1) PVC
2) PV
They showed as terminating and was left for the weekend. Upon arriving this morning they still showed as terminating so deleted both PVC and PV forcefully. No joy.
To fix the whole thing I had to delete the stateful set.

Is this correct if you wanted to delete the PV?

Answer (score 70):

You can delete the PV using following two commands:

```
kubectl delete pv <pv_name> --grace-period=0 --force
```

And then deleting the finalizer using:

```
kubectl patch pv <pv_name> -p '{"metadata": {"finalizers": null}}'
```

Comment: If the PVC still exists, this will set the state of the PVC to `Lost`. I was forced to re-create the PVC to get it to create a new PV.

Comment: that's absolutely not how it's done!

Comment: This just removes the PV from `etcd` (or whatever key-value store you use) without verifying that it is actually deleted, very potentially leaving the relevant objects dangling. A significantly more correct answer is provided by @ns15.

Comment: Although you should follow the answer provided by @ns15, as stated by Alwyn. This can help if you previously did not follow it. 
That is: For some reason, you deleted the PVC, but the PV didn't get deleted (maybe the provisioner was not able to detach the disk from the VM Host). Then you manually detached the disk and deleted it, and the PV gets "stuck" in K8s. 
Trying to delete the pv with kubectl lead to a permanen Terminating state. 
Thus you should remove the finalizer with kubectl patch.

Answer (score 17):

It worked for me if I first delete the pvc, then the pv

```
kubectl delete pvc data-p-0
kubectl delete pv  <pv-name>  --grace-period=0 --force
```

Assuming one wants to delete the pvc as well, seems to hang otherwise

Answer (score 12):

Firstly run `kubectl patch pv {PVC_NAME} -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'`

then run `kubectl delete pv {PVC_NAME}`

Comment: Perhaps, these two commands need to be inverted to run, as @PrafullLadha said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54630036/3814775). Actually I tried myself. In order to delete the PV successfully, I have to run the delete command first (which would be stuck, have to use ctrl-c to get back), then use the patch command to delete the `finalizers` .

Answer (score 10):

Most answers on this thread simply mention the commands without explaining the root cause.

Here is a diagram to help understand better.
refer to my other answer for commands and additional info -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/73534207/6563567

**This diagram shows how to clean delete a volume**
[image]

In your case, the PVC and PV are stuck in terminating state because of finalizers. Finalizers are guard rails in k8s to avoid accidental deletion of resources.

Your observations are correct and this is how Kubernetes works. But the order in which you deleted the resources are incorrect.

**This is what happened,**

PV is stuck terminating because PVC still exists. PVC is stuck terminating because Statefulsets(pods) are still using the volumes. (volumes are attached to the nodes and mounted to the pods). As soon as you deleted the pods/STS, since volumes are no more in use, PVC and PV got successfully removed.

Answer (score 6):

At the beginning be sure that your `Reclaim Policy` is set up to `Delete`. After PVC is deleted, PV should be deleted.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming

If it doesn't help, please check this [closed] Kubernetes PV issue:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69697

and try to delete the PV finalizers.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**: PV volumes may be described like `pvc-name-of-volume` which may be confusing!

- PV: `Persistent Volume`
- PVC: `Persistent Volume Clame`
- Pod -> PVC -> PV -> Host Machine

---

1. First find the pvs: `kubectl get pv -n {namespace}`
2. Then delete the **pv** in order set status to `Terminating`

`kubectl delete pv {PV_NAME}`

3. Then patch it to set the status of **pvc** to `Lost`:
   `kubectl patch pv {PV_NAME} -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'`
4. Then get pvc volumes: `kubectl get pvc -n storage`
5. Then you can delete the **pvc**:
   `kubectl delete pvc {PVC_NAME} -n {namespace}`

---

###### Theoretical example:

** Lets say we have kafka installed in `storage namespace`

`$ kubectl get pv -n storage`

`$ kubectl delete pv pvc-ccdfe297-44c9-4ca7-b44c-415720f428d1`

`$ kubectl get pv -n storage` (hanging but turns pv status to terminating)

`$ kubectl patch pv pvc-ccdfe297-44c9-4ca7-b44c-415720f428d1 -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'`

`$ kubectl get pvc -n storage`

`kubectl delete pvc data-kafka-0 -n storage`

Answer (score 3):

For me I followed this method and it worked fine for me.

```
kubectl delete pv {your-pv-name} --grace-period=0 --force
```

After that edit the pvc configuration.

```
kubectl edit pvc {your-pvc-name}
```

and remove finalizer from pvc configuration.

```
finalizers:
  -  kubernetes.io/pv-protection
```

You can read more about finalizer here in official kubernetes guide.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#finalizers

Answer (score 0):

> kubectl delete pv [pv-name]

ksu you have to check about the policy of PV it should not be Reclaim Policy.