# How to delete persistent volumes in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I am trying to delete persistent volumes on a Kubernetes cluster. I ran the following command:

```
kubectl delete pv pvc-08e65270-b7ce-11e9-ba0b-0a1e280502e2 pvc-08e87826-b7ce-11e9-ba0b-0a1e280502e2 pvc-08ea5f97-b7ce-11e9-ba0b-0a1e280502e2 pvc-08ec1cac-b7ce-11e9-ba0b-0a1e280502e2
```

However it showed:

```
persistentvolume "pvc-08e65270-b7ce-11e9-ba0b-0a1e280502e2" deleted
persistentvolume "pvc-08e87826-b7ce-11e9-ba0b-0a1e280502e2" deleted
persistentvolume "pvc-08ea5f97-b7ce-11e9-ba0b-0a1e280502e2" deleted
persistentvolume "pvc-08ec1cac-b7ce-11e9-ba0b-0a1e280502e2" deleted
```

But the command did not exit. So I `CONTROL+C` to force exit the command. After a few minutes, I ran:

```
kubectl get pv
```

And the status is `Terminating`, but the volumes don't appear to be deleting.

How can I delete these persistent volumes?

Comment: Which provisioner do you use? I think the command is just waiting your provisioner to delete the volume, it looks like something goes wrong. Please provide the log from kubelet, or log from provisioner if you use kubernetes-csi.

Comment: In my case the trick was not only to delete the 'claims' but also the relate 'persistent volumes' (the pods were already gone since I got rid of the related 'services', 'deployments' etc.). Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 81):

It is not recommended to delete pv it should be handled by cloud provisioner. If you need to remove pv just delete pod bounded to claim and then pvc. After that cloud provisioner should also remove pv as well.

```
kubectl delete pvc --all
```

It sometimes could take some time so be patient.

Comment: The pods are deleted. They were originally created by a Helm chart. I don't think when I did `helm delete` it deletes the PV volumes. The PV volumes are still showing `Terminating`, been over 40 minutes.

Comment: Once I deleted pv on gke and it took more than an hour for kubernetes to figure out what happened.

Comment: @Justin `helm delete` only deletes the pvc and it depends on the reclaim policy of the pv to determine whether it is retained or deleted

Comment: @FL3SH Please fix the type in `kubectl`

Comment: had no issues with this on v1.21

Answer (score 43):

Delete all the pods, which is using the pvc(you want to delete), then delete the  PVC(PersistentVolumeClaim) & PV(PersistentVolume) in sequence.

Some thing like below(in sequence):

1. kubectl delete pod --all / pod-name
2. kubectl delete pvc --all / pvc-name
3. kubectl delete pv --all / pv-name

Comment: I deleted my PV by mistake, when I tried to get all pv in specific namespace, it's returned all pv in my cluster. So I thought it was pv in this namespace, so I deleted all of these PV. But luckily, these PV won't get delete by the above rules. Feeling relieve ^^

Answer (score 37):

I have created below diagram to help explain this better.

[image]

The Kubectl commands are mentioned by other answers in this thread. The same should work.

```
kubectl delete sts sts-name
kubectl delete pvc pvc-name
kubectl delete pv pv-name
```

---

**Some more useful info**

- If you see something stuck in terminating state, its because of guardrails set in place by k8s. These are referred to as '[Finalizers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/finalizers/#how-finalizers-work)'.
- If your PV is stuck in terminating state after deletion, it likely because you have deleted the PV before deleting the PVC.
- If your PVC is stuck in terminating state after deletion, it likely because your pods are still running. (simply delete the pods/statefulset in such cases)
- If you wish to delete the resource in terminating state, use below commands to bypass the pvc, pv protection finalizers.

`kubectl patch pvc pvc_name -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'`

`kubectl patch pv pv_name -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'`

---

- Here is the documentation on [PVC retention policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#persistentvolumeclaim-retention).
- Here is the documentation on [PV reclaim policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming).

Comment: Just wanted to note that this is the exact summation I've been looking for!

Answer (score 9):

*PVs* are cluster resources provisioned by an administrator, whereas *PVCs* are a user's request for storage and resources. I guess you have still deployed the corresponding *PVC*.

1. Delete the deployment. E.g.:

   [image]

   ```
   kubectl delete deployment mongo-db
   ```
2. List the *Persistent Volume Claim*. E.g.:

   [image]

   ```
   kubectl get pvc
   ```
3. Delete the corresponding *pcv*. E.g.:

   [image]

   ```
   kubectl delete pvc mongo-db
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Someone above said just delete pod bounded to claim and then pvc is true, because delete pv one by one takes longer time.

I think just leave it as it is after pod and pvc deleted is good.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).