# Kubernetes: How can I delete all PVC that have a specific word in their name?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to delete all PersistentVolumeClaim in Kubernetes that have **claim** word in their name.

for example: **claim-me-dot-com**

How can I do it? thanks.

Comment: Try this...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401526/how-to-delete-persistent-volumes-in-kubernetes      YOU should check current namespace.

Comment: @J.Song I check it. it won't solve my problem. thanks.

Comment: `kubectl get pvc -n nextera -o name | cut -d/ -f2 | grep claim better answer – 
nader 1 min ago`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to delete all PVCs whose names contain *claim*. You should check every namespace and then delete the PVC in that namespace. Otherwise, you may delete important PVCs.

```
export NAMESPACE=your-name-space
export DELETE_PHRASE=claim
kubectl get pvc -n NAMESPACE --no-headers=true | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep $DELETE_PHRASE | xargs kubectl delete pvc -n $NAMESPACE
```

To delete in bulk, you can use this `for` script to delete all of the PVCs. Use this at your own **RISK**

```
for ns in `kubectl get ns --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"`; 
    for pvc in `kubectl get pvc -n $ns --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | grep claim`;
        kubectl delete pvc $pvc -n $ns;
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution below is restricted to the current namespace:

```
kubectl get pvc -o name | grep "claim-me-dot-com" | xargs -n 1 kubectl delete
```

To delete pvc from all namespaces:

```
kubectl get pvc -o name -A | grep "claim-me-dot-com" | xargs -n 1 kubectl delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to delete multiple objects based on their labels.

e.g.

```
kubectl delete pvc -l 'app.kubernetes.io/component in (<FIRST_VALUE>, <SECOND_VALUE>)'
```